# Create a hidden directory from deployment.properties

Tags: java, windows, hidden-files

Is it possible in a Windows 7 environment to do the following in your java deployment.properties file:

```
deployment.user.security.trusted.certs=H\:\\hiddendir\\trusted.certs
```

but when it creates hiddendir the directory is hidden

e.g. on Linux you could put a dot in front H:\.hiddendir

is there anything similar on Windows 7

Comment: It's not elegant, but this might work `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H  <dir>");`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using this strictly on a native environment you can use an attribute with the Runtime.exec() method. There is nothing solely in the Java API which could be used.

An example:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +h " + src.getPath());
```

You can refer to [attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true).

However, if you are unaware of the native environment, you can create an OS check to provide different hidden file properties.

ie.

```
private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

public static boolean isWindows() {
    return (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if isWindows(){
      //then do
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really just wondering without using java code is there a way to edit this line in deployment.properties so it creates a hidden folder deployment.user.security.trusted.certs=H\:\\hiddendir\\trusted.certs . If its not possible then thats ok and the only solution is to code something then thats fine . thanks for your help

Comment: deployment.user.security.trusted.certs=attrib +s +h \dir\

Comment: tring deployment.user.security.trusted.certs=attrib +s +h \H\:\\hiddendirect\

\trusted.certs\ which doesn't seem to work. is it as easy as this?